# unmounting duplicate partition

Tags: ubuntu

so ages ago i wanted to have separate partition for guests i issues some commands i dont recall, i want to undo the changes here is what i found so far

```
an@usr1:~$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME   FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT        LABEL
sda             1.8T                   
├─sda1           16M                   
└─sda2 ntfs     1.8T /mesia/data       New Volume
sdb             3.7T                   
└─sdb1 ext3     3.7T /media/hdd2/Gusts hdd2
sdc           232.9G                   
├─sdc1 vfat     512M /boot/efi         
└─sdc2 ext4   232.4G /                 
an@usr1:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  2.5M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/sdc2       228G  172G   45G  80% /
tmpfs            16G  174M   16G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2       1.9T  1.3T  616G  67% /mesia/data
/dev/sdc1       511M  5.3M  506M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs           3.2G   64K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           3.2G   24K  3.2G   1% /run/user/125
/dev/sdb1       3.6T  1.6T  1.9T  47% /media/hdd2
an@usr1:~$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=16361356k,nr_inodes=4090339,mode=755,inode64)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=3280516k,mode=755,inode64)
/dev/sdc2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k,inode64)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755,inode64)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/misc type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,misc)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=29,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=32353)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/sda2 on /mesia/data type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096,x-gvfs-show)
/dev/sdc1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
vmware-vmblock on /run/vmblock-fuse type fuse.vmware-vmblock (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=3280512k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000,inode64)
tmpfs on /run/user/125 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=3280512k,mode=700,uid=125,gid=130,inode64)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/125/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=125,group_id=130)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/hdd2 type ext3 (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,x-gvfs-show)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/hdd2/Gusts type ext3 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/fuse on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
an@usr1:~$
```

[image: what i see in file explorer]

is it safe to unmount the duplicate partition?

```
sudo umount /media/hdd2/Gusts
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, you have `/dev/sdb1` mounted in two locations: `/media/hdd2` and `/media/hdd2/Gusts`.  You would like to remove the `Gusts` mount.

> is it safe to unmount the duplicate partition?

Yes.  And the command `sudo umount /media/hdd2/Gusts` will do that.

However, if this is mounted on startup, then the mount will return when you reboot.  You can remove mounting on startup by editing `/etc/fstab`.  There will be a line similar to:

```
/dev/sdb1    /media/hdd2/Gusts   ext4   defaults    0  0
```

To prevent future mounts to `/media/hdd2/Gusts` remove that entire line.

Comment: This did it thanks

Comment: @microblackhole If this answer has fixed your issue, please accept the answer so others know the issue is resolved.  If not, please leave comments to get more help.